# Scraping website using Celery

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, celery

Currently, my structure is `Flask, Redis, RabbitMQ and Celery`. In my scraping, I am using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. 
My flask is running on apache and wsgi. This is on prod. With `app.run(threaded=True)`

I have 25 APIs. 10 are to scrape the URL like headers, etc. , and the rest is to use a 3rd party API for that URL.

I am using chord for processing my APIs and getting data from the APIs using `requests`.

For my chord header I have 3 workers, while on my callback I only have 1.
I am having a bottleneck issue of having `ConnectTimeoutError` and `MaxRetryError`. As I read some thread it said to do a timeout for every process, because having this error means you are overloading the remote server.

The problem is since I am using a chord there is no sense to use a time sleep since the 25 API call will be run at the same time. Have anyone encountered this? Or am I doing this wrong?

The thread I read seem to be saying to change the requests to pycurl or use Scrapy. But I dont think that's the case since `ConnectTimeoutError` is about my host overloading a specific URLs server.

My chord process:

```
callback = create_document.s(url, company_logo, api_list)
header = [api_request.s(key) for key in api_list.keys()]
result = chord(header)(callback)
```

In api_request task requests is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to limit the number of scrapes running at the same time you can create an enqueue task that checks to see if another task is running that shares the same properties as the task you are wanting to run.  If the task is running you tell it to sleep for a few seconds and check again.  When it sees that one is not running you can then queue the task you want to run.  This will allow you to have sleeps with asynchronous tasks. You can even count the tasks and run more if only a certain number are running.  With this you can run 5 at a time and see if it is throttled enough then queue another when you see one has finished etc.

::EDIT::

[Documentation for Celery Inspect](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html)

Comment: Do you have a link to a documentation or a sample code?

Comment: I added a reference link for you.

Comment: celery inspect is really slow and not reliable, just set a redis key or whatever and check yourself